# How to define a problem matcher for cppcheck task in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, cppcheck, vscode-tasks

I am setting up a "cppcheck" task for the vscode. It works, but problems are not captured with problem matcher.

I have tried "$gcc" problem matcher and also some custom configurations.

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "cppcheck",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "cppcheck --template=gcc --enable=style --project=${workspaceFolder}/build/compile_commands.json",
            "problemMatcher": "$gcc",
        }
    ]
}
```

or this:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "cppcheck",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "cppcheck --template=gcc --enable=warning src/jc_certreq.cpp",
            "problemMatcher": {
                "owner": "cpp",
                "fileLocation": "absolute",
                "pattern": {
                    "regexp": "^(.*):(\\d+):(\\d+):\\s+(warning|error):\\s+(.*)$",
                    "file": 1,
                    "line": 2,
                    "column": 3,
                    "severity": 4,
                    "message": 5
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The terminal for example shows such error:

```
/home/user/workspace/project/myprogram.c:440: error: Memory leak: exts
```

But it does not appear in "problems" bar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was looking for a solution to this myself, but could only find this unanswered question. So I went ahead and tinkered with it a little and eventually got it working.

The issue seems to be that older versions of Cppcheck (I'm using version 1.82) do not offer support for printing the column yet. It looks like support for that [wasn't added until Cppcheck 1.84](https://github.com/danmar/cppcheck/commit/f058d9ad083a6111e9339b4b3506c5da7db579e0). However, the default `$gcc` problem matcher [expects the column number to be present](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/blob/master/Extension/package.json#L54-L60).

This is an example of a message Cppcheck 1.82 prints when using the gcc template:

```
utilities/thread/condition.h:12: warning: The class 'Condition' has 'copy constructor' but lack of 'operator='.
```

While an error printed by GCC 6.3 looks like this:

```
dump_tool.c:40:36: fatal error: generated/autoconf.h: No such file or directory
```

They're pretty much identical, except for the missing column number. Simply removing that from the pattern resolved the issue for me. The problems are matched and show up in the problems tab.

In addition to that, I adjusted my `severity` to `warning` so that those appear in the problems tab as well, and I changed the `fileLocation` to `relative` as I'm working with relative paths.

This is the complete task definition I use for my project:

```json
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        // ...
        {
            "label": "cppcheck",
            "group": "build",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "cppcheck --template=gcc --enable=warning --std=c++03 --force .",
            "problemMatcher": {
                "fileLocation": "relative",
                "severity": "warning",
                "pattern":{
                    "regexp": "^(.*):(\\d+):\\s+(warning|error):\\s+(.*)$",
                    "file": 1,
                    "location": 2,
                    "severity": 3,
                    "message": 4
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.[Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I went ahead and modified my answer to provide more context and references. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue, but with an old gcc compiler, which I am forced to use. I elaborated on @Ditti 's solution, because this compiler prints some warnings/errors with column number and some without. I also put the problem matcher at the top of my task file so that it applies to all tasks.

I also use `line` instead of `location`. When using `location`, the `column` was not correctly used in the problems pane. Maybe `location` would serve line and column and thus `column` remained unused. But when specifying `line` and `column` separately it now works for both of my test cases below.

```json
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "problemMatcher":{
        "pattern":[
            {
                "regexp": "^(.*?):(\\d+):(\\d*):?\\s+(warning|error):\\s+(.*)$",
                "file": 1,
                "line": 2,
                "column": 3,
                "severity": 4,
                "message": 5
            }
        ]
    },
    "tasks": [
        {
       //...
        }
    ]
}
```

My test cases are:

```
File.c:416:10: warning: #warning test
File.c:423: error: [12874] conflicting types for 'test'
C:\Path\to\file.c:423: error: [12874] conflicting types for 'test'
C:\Path\to\file.c:416:10 error: [12874] conflicting types for 'test'
```

edit: I was made aware that my original solution was not working with windows style full paths, because of the colon after the drive letter. So I changed the first group to lazy matching.